# Outlook add-in can't input successful when use Surface

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin

I'm developing an outlook windows desktop add-in, When I use the surface to testing, then I found that I can't input successfully. it seems no focus event at add-in panel. When I touch the input box at my add-in the keyboard can wake up successful but can't input any character

In fact:
I have tried to update the chromium version, but it still can't work.

Expected result:
I can use Surface to input character on outlook add-in.
[This is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6dnx.png)

Comment: Which Outlook Client are you using - Outlook Windows or Outlook on Web?

Comment: It's an Outlook Windows add-in.

Comment: Can you please provide any screenshots ?

Comment: Also please clarify you say "Outlook Windows Add-in" Is this Outlook Desktop Win 32 Client? But you also Mention "Chromium" which is NOT Outlook Windows? (again providing full screenshots may help clarify what the problem is)

Comment: It's an Outlook Desktop Win 32 Client. And I have added a screenshot to post.

Comment: The screenshot looks like you aren't using display dialog but using something else to pop up the window. Is it default browser?

Comment: It's no default browser. It's an add-in panel.